# Compile error for FsLab journal template

Tags: f#, fslab

I just downloaded the FSlab journal template from fslab.org.  when I try to run the tutorial.fsx I get a number of errors in the build.fsx.  These errors seem to be specific to the suave library. 
The first issue is “open Suave.HTTP.Files” apparently there is no Files namespace.
Second, the script uses an UTF8 data type that cannot be found.
Third, the script also uses an Applicatives type that cannot be found.

When I went on github to look at Suave I found that the Suave.HTTP.Files namespace had been deprecated in favor of Suave.Files but when I added that namespace it didn’t fix anything.

I am using paket to pull the latest versions of all the dependencies.  I am using VS 2013.

Is there some step in FsLab journal template that I am missing?  Is the latest version of Suave no longer compatible with FsLab?

Answer (score 2):

Can you please open an issue for this on [FsLab's GitHub](http://github.com/fslaborg/FsLab.Templates/)?

The FsLab template always gets the latest version of all dependencies, which works fine when there are no breaking API changes. Suave 1.0 (released just now) went through a lot of much needed cleanup, but it has breaking API changes.

We'll need to update the template to the latest version of Suave. In the meantime, you can explicitly require version 0.33.0. I just [did this change in the template](https://github.com/fslaborg/FsLab.Templates/commit/46941673347fc2c85977961a99f14eff54ee2a4f) - all you need to do is to add the version number in `paket.dependencies`:

```
nuget FsLab  
nuget FsLab.Runner  
nuget FAKE  
nuget Suave 0.33.0
```

When you change the last line as above after downloading the template, things should work!